# Is There A Fake Re-starter On Windows ?

Tags: windows-8, reboot

For example if I installed a driver I must restart , is there any way to fool the computer , like ( restart withou restart) .

Comment: Not really, because the regular restart for Win8 is already pretty close to just that.

Comment: Your system will be nicely unstable after your fake restart. There's a reason for a full reinitialization.

Comment: Usually you can just say no when it prompts you to restart. (At least you can with any properly programmed software; though just this afternoon, I happened to install a Hauppauge program which restarted without notice and left me spitting mad. Fortunately I didn’t have anything critical running at the time.) Anyway, it depends on *why* it wants to reboot, *what* it does when it shuts down *and* reboots, and *how* it does it. In any case, this sounds like an [XP problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: No, because the main reason those drivers need a restart is because they need some files to be unloaded, replaced, and then reloaded. If some unknown number of programs are using the file then it is not feasible to force the replacement as the programs may crash fatally and cause serious problems. You need the reboot to process the replacement cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After driver installation the driver creates startup entries in your Windows Services. Your driver services will start when you will restart your computer. Go on and try starting your driver's services from Windows Services. You will be greeted by an error 'A reboot is required'. A fake restart may fake the windows but wont load the drivers. Drivers are loaded only when you start your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize beforehand because I'm not really answering your question, but there is no good reason why you should do a "fake restart".

Why? The system only loads drivers at startup (most important drivers anyways). Drivers are a big deal in computing - they interface you with the rest of your machine. In a sense, without them you couldn't run it.

Drivers are assigned a specific address in memory at startup, by mechanisms that fall outside of what `explorer` does, and are usually locked, as to prevent corruption and user access. Assuming their positions could change by user action, all programs that depend on those drivers would need to know that the driver's positions or their contents have been changed. That would reak havoc for all applications because as I said, `explorer` doesn't do anything with drivers.

Trying to perform a "fake restart" by closing and opening `explorer.exe` can do one of three actions:

- Do nothing, as drivers *are* loaded at startup.
- Mess up the computer. This is assuming your drivers are somehow tied with `explorer`.
- Actually work. This happens when it isn't a "relevant" driver (i.e. graphics, audio, motherboard, etc), like in the case of a touchpad or a keyboard.

But it is best to allow the system lo load the drivers their natural way, that is, by performing a restart.

However, no one says when you need to restart your computer...